# form.serialize() does not pick already set select fields

Tags: javascript

I have been using the jquery serialize() function to serialize the values of a form in a Modal and submit it via ajax.This works fine all feilds excepting select2 dropdown for few feilds.

I have a country and state feild. I am setting these feilds via jquery after calling a external script.

```js
function openeditmodal(){
$('.edit').click(function() { 

   $('#editModal').on('show', function(){
       $.getScript("js/editlocation.js");

    });
   $("#editcountryId").select2("data", {text:  $(this).attr('data-country') });
     $("#editstateId").select2("data", { text:  $(this).attr('data-state') });
     $("#editcityId").select2("data", { text:  $(this).attr('data-city') });

})
}

$(function() {
     $("#saveemployee").click(function(){  
      var form = $('.updateemployee').serializeArray();
        alert(form);//doesnt capture data of select2 dropdown
})
```

```html
<div class="modal hide in" id = "editModal">
<form  class = "updateemployee">
<select name="ccountry" class="editcountries" id="editcountryId" required>
<select name="cstate" class="editstates"  id="editstateId" required >
<button type="submit"  id = "saveemployee">Save</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show an element with class `updateemployee`, also nested form elements is invalid html

Comment: Since serializeArray only serializes [successful controls](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) I would make sure the missing ones fulfill the criteria of being successful.

Comment: You haven't loaded jQuery or the Select2 plugin in the snippet. There's also a Javascript syntax error.